# Matlab Empty Dimensions with NIFTI format

Tags: matlab, dimensions

I am loading some .NII files containing brain atlases into Matlab using this package: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29344-read-medical-data-3d

I have used the above package many times to load .MHA files successfully.

But when I load any NIFTI file, I get a volume with wacky dimensions like the following:

```
197 x 233 x 189 x 1 x 1 x 0 x 0
```

I would expect a volume of size 197 x 233 x 189, but why there are two singleton dimensions and two empty dimensions is unknown to me.

I don't know much about the NIFTI format, perhaps the above has a reasonable explanation?

If not, I would like to somehow remove the empty dimensions so I can get at the first three. So far I've had no luck with what seems like a pretty simple operation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sqeeze() [1]?

[1] http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html

Trailing singleton dimensions are quite common in Matlab code, especially from user-contributed code. Zero-dimensions are not, as far as I know.

Comment: Yup, squeeze gets rid of the singletons, but its the empty ones which are problematic.